# Where does Chrome store synchronized settings?

Tags: google-chrome, sync

Google Chrome uses Google Docs to synchronize the bookmark list among multiple installations. Where does it store the other settings it synchronizes, like AutoFill, extensions, preferences, and themes? Is that information viewable or editable (besides within Chrome itself)?

Answer (score 1):

Google says the data is [stored within your Google account,](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139) but doesn't mention where exactly it is saved.

The bookmarks can be viewed, but not edited